# Access Windows Server 2008R2 Remote Desktop Service RD Web Access RemoteApp from UBUNTU 14.04

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, webapps, rdp

All my office computers are running in Windows. However at home I have Ubuntu 14.04 x64 bit running on my laptop. Few days back, I got a opportunity to work from home. To do this, my friends (using Windows 8) access company webpage and then navigate to "RD Web Access" page and launch office softwares as RemoteApp.

If I try that from my laptop, the RD Web Access page does not come up right and also does not let me launch RemoteApps (my company software).

NOTE: To workaround that problem, I can install a Windows VM in virtualbox but that is something I want to do at the last. In my friend circle I always encourage others to use Ubuntu, please help me to not use a Windows VM.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm sorry but expecting an update/response.
Please help !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced something similar in recent past in my office.

The IT Admin of my office tried something called WinConn (RemoteApp Manager). The application is build for Quantal (12.10) not sure about yours.

I think its worth a try.